# PHP adding a character into variable

Tags: php, variables, character

I have a form that when submitted loads in the post id into a variable. However some of the options in the form have spaces between the words. For example

one option is "Kanye West" now it loads into the variable the words Kanye and West with a space inbetween.

I need to be able to add a + symbol between these two words instead of a space. So it would be Kanye+West. How would i go about doing this?

Comment: I got here by searching for Kanye West. Thumbs Up if you did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [urlencode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function was designed exactly for this purpose.  It converts all special characters (including space) to their url-safe equivalents (e.g. `+`).

Comment: how would i do this, on this code - $artistResult = $_POST['select']; (select for example would be Kanye West)

Comment: `$artistResult = urlencode($_POST['select']);` (Not too tough, eh?)

Comment: @DIM3NSION That would be `$artistResult = urlencode($_POST['select']);`, with `$_POST['select'] = 'Kanye West'` giving `$artistResult = 'Kanye+West'`. (Edit: Too slow ... again.)

Answer (score 4):

Simple case: [`strtr()`](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php)

```
$str = strtr($str, ' ', '+');
```

Generic: [`urlencode()`](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

```
$str = urlencode($str);
```

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`strtr()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php):

```
$str = strtr(trim($str), ' ', '+');
```

If you want to replace *several consecutive* white space characters with *one* `+`, use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$str = preg_replace('/\s+/','+', trim($str));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `str_replace(' ', '+', $originalString)` on the PHP side before output.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

$my_new_string = str_replace(" ", "+", $my_oldstring)

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'Kanye West';
$str = str_replace(' ', '+', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

$var; // from your post
   $var = str_replace(" ", "+",$var);